# regular expression using group reference

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression but do not know what does it means

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(u'(^| )'0,u'\g<1>null','0fa0a')
```

I expect it to replace the begin of string or empty space will null, but actual does nothing.

```
>>> '0fa0a'
```

What does the group reference refer to ? I haven't defined group 1?
Why does it not replace ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in here,

```
re.sub(u'(^| )'0,u'\g<1>null','0fa0a')
               |
```

Include the `0` within the single quotes.

```
re.sub(u'(^| )0',u'\g<1>null','0fa0a')
```

output:

```
u'nullfa0a'
```

If you don't want to remove the starting `0` then don't include that in your pattern.

```
>>> re.sub(u'(^| )',u'\g<1>null','0fa0a')
'null0fa0a'
```

If you want to check whether the start or the space is followed by 0 then use a lookahead,

```
>>> re.sub(u'(^| )(?=0)',u'\g<1>null','0fa0a')
u'null0fa0a'
```